# What Type of Integral Equation is this: $u(x)=\sin x-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x(x-t)^2dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Saw a question where I was told to convert the integral equation below into an IVP:

$$u(x)=\sin x-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x(x-t)^2dt$$

Notice that there's no unknown function in the integral. Is it possible to have this kind of Integral Equation? If yes, what type of Equation is it?

I also tried solving it nonetheless:

$$u(x)=\sin x-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x(x-t)^2dt$$

$$u'=\cos x -\int_0^x(x-t)dt$$

$$u''=-\sin x-\int_0^xdt$$
$$u'''=-\cos x-1$$

Thus I arrived at the following IVP:

$$u'''+\cos x+1=0$$
$$u(0)=0, u'(0)=1, u''(0)=0$$

Am I right?

Comment: Everything looks okay.

Comment: So what type of Integral Equation is it @JackyChong? Is it a Volterra Integral Equation?

Comment: This is correct. You could have done faster using $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^x(x-t)^2\,dt=-\frac{x^3}{6}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici my major concern is to know what type of Integral Equation is it

Comment: To me, it is a trivial third order differential equation.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici would it be also safe to call it a Volterra Integral Equation?